# palm rejection on Samsung tab

Tags: android, touch

I am facing problem with palm touch on Samsung tab.but i want to reject this palm touch,only allow stylus pen touch.

I tried this code,

```
float lastvalue = event.getSize();
```

but this give same value for palm touch and pen touch.

Answer (score 1):

Use getToolType.  It returns the touch device-  finger, stylus, mouse, etc.  Size won't remotely do what you want.  Not only does it only give relative values, but it isn't universally supported.